# Regex to remove name titles leaving forename in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a set of names and wish to extract the forename from each. However, some have Mr, Mrs etc and others don't.

How can I extract the titles and then pull the first word(forename) out?

This is what I have so far.

`^(Miss|Mr|Lady|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Mr.|Sir)\b`

Here is an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dtKmQ_cGYcMTbG1GVAQwNTvHAns8926rU7bFakDH0dI/edit?usp=sharing

A copy can be made by using File-Make a copy

Comment: Don't forget royal prefixes (Count, Prince, Queen...).

Comment: @AmigoJack, i had to think of countries where people's first names like Prince, Princess, Queen are not uncommon :) haha. Could throw some second level of complicity over this query.

Comment: @JvdV I think the answer may be dependent on the origin countries of the population that we want to support and the correctness threshold we want to achieve. Also if going for simple prefix matching rules there may be a problem with expanding the ruleset, think Duke or X Æ A-Xii.

Comment: Have you had any chance of trying out my solution from the answer below? I tested it in GS and it seems to provide the results you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^(?:(?:(?:Miss|Mr|Lady|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Sir)\b|Mr\.)\s+)?(\S+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbVBz4/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:(?:Miss|Mr|Lady|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Sir)\b|Mr\.)\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `(?:(?:Miss|Mr|Lady|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Sir)\b|Mr\.)` - a non-capturing group matching either

    - `(?:Miss|Mr|Lady|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Sir)\b` - a whole word `Miss`, `Mr`, `Lady`, `Mrs`, `Ms`, `Dr`, `Sir`
    - `|` - or
    - `Mr\.` - `Mr.` (`\b` after `\.` requires a word charon the right, hence it is a separate branch)
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group (actual output): 1 or more non-whitespace characters.